# Distance between non-negative elements of two vectors

Tags: numpy, vector, numpy-ndarray

I have two vectors:

```
v1 = [1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6]
v2 = [2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1]
```

I need to compute a distance that is the absolute value of the positive elements **on that respective position**. For example, the above is:

```
D(v1, v2) = D(v2, v1) = Abs(1-2) + Abs(2-1) + Abs(6-1) = 7
```

How can I implement this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I found with numpy:

```
v1 = np.array(v1)
v2 = np.array(v2)
sum(abs(v1[(v1>0)&(v2>0)] - v2[(v1>0)&(v2>0)]))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: v1 and v2 are vectors, you cannot compare them to 0.

Comment: I used `np.array` for v1 and v2. Forgot to mention

Comment: @Qubix you can.